# Integral of the product of two functions

Tags: integration, integral-equations, integral-transforms

I don't know if it is something trivial and well-known, or something that depends on more conditions.

Assume $f:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a multivariate strictly positive function defined in $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ and with a finite integral, i.e. $\int_{\boldsymbol{x}\in \mathbb{R}^d} f(\boldsymbol{x})\text{d}\boldsymbol{x} < K$ for certain $K > 0$.

Consider two functions $g_1$, $g_2$ with the form 
$$g_i(\boldsymbol{x}) = e^{(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu_i})^T\boldsymbol{\Sigma_i}(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu_i})},\;\; i\in {1,2}$$
with $\boldsymbol{\mu_i} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $\Sigma_i$ a symmetric positive definite $d\times d$ matrix. Can I conclude that if we have
$$
\int_{\boldsymbol{x}\in \mathbb{R}^d} f(\boldsymbol{x}) g_1(\boldsymbol{x}) \text{d}\boldsymbol{x} = \int_{\boldsymbol{x}\in \mathbb{R}^d} f(\boldsymbol{x}) g_2(\boldsymbol{x}) \text{d}\boldsymbol{x}
$$
then, we must have $g_1(\boldsymbol{x})  = g_2(\boldsymbol{x})$?

Comment: Take $f=g_1=g_2$ on the exterior of the unit ball. Let $f=1$ on the unit ball, $g_1$ also equal to $1$ on the ball except a little ball around $(1/2,0,0...,0)$ on which it has a bump. Let $g_2$ be just like $g_1$ but with an identical bump at a different location of the unit ball.

Comment: @conditionalMethod thank you for your comment. Indeed, you are completely right. Nice and easy counterexample! Allow me to define better my functions $g_1$ and $g_2$ in such a way they fit better to my current problem. (I have just rewritten my question)